# What is causing java.net.SocketTimeoutException while using BufferedReader on Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, bufferedreader, socket-timeout-exception

I'm using a BufferedReader in an Android app to retrieve an XML file from a webserver.  The code that I have currently works with a number of other files.  However for this particular file I am getting a SocketTimeoutException.  Below is my code:

```
socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(address, intPort), 5000);
String data;
socket.setSoTimeout(5000); //timeout after X milliseconds
dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
dos.write(requestmsg.getBytes());
dos.flush();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((data = dis.readLine()) != null)
    sb.append(data);

returnData = sb.toString();
```

When I look at the buffer for dis, I can see the whole file there:

[Screenshot of the buffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kb29G.png)

But it throws the exception after reading in this much:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OKCache-Control: no-storeContent-Type: text/xmlContent-Length: 215
```

Here is the file that I am trying to read in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><datavalues>...</datavalues>
```

Here is my logcat output from the error:

```
11-05 08:22:41.551 3750-3779/ W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
11-05 08:22:41.553 3750-3779/ W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:492)
11-05 08:22:41.555 3750-3779/ W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
11-05 08:22:41.556 3750-3779/ W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
11-05 08:22:41.558 3750-3779/ W/System.err:     at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:233)
11-05 08:22:41.560 3750-3779/ W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:145)
11-05 08:22:41.562 3750-3779/ W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:397)    
…
11-05 08:22:41.568 3750-3779/ W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
11-05 08:22:41.570 3750-3779/ W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-05 08:22:41.572 3750-3779/ W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
11-05 08:22:41.573 3750-3779/ W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-05 08:22:41.574 3750-3779/ W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-05 08:22:41.575 3750-3779/ W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I'm not sure if the issue is in the XML file, or if there is something that I need to change in my code.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if socket is connected before read incoming data via [isConnected](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#isConnected()) method

in your case

```
if(socket.isConnected()){
// read  output stream socket.getOutputStream()
}else{
 // make another try ...  
 }
```